# ¿Como puedo dibujar un plano cartesiano con un array 2D en python?

Tags: python, array, arraylist, pygame

tengo una duda, en estos últimos días tuve una duda mientras aprendía Python, el problema es el como puedo dibujar un plano cartesiano con un array 2D en python, pero no en la terminal, como en pygame que tiene una interfaz. Con botones y etc.

Mi proyecto es crear un plano cartesiano que pueda dibujar figuras geométricas en ella funciones etc. pero con puro array en 2D.

Esto es un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer. 
que librería me recomendarían usar, soy novato en Python.

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se llama una interfaz gráfica de usuario (GUI), y tienes bastantes opciones, ninguna de ellas simple, ya te aviso. La que ya viene preinstalada en python y puedes usar inmediatamente se llama `tkinter`. Otras bastante populares son PyQt y wxPython. Incluso si lo que quieres hacer no tiene muchos "widgets" (botones, menús, listas desplegables, checkboxes, tablas, etc) sino más bien gráficos, el propio PyGame podría servirte, aunque no está pensado para eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, averiguare sobre lo que me has mencionado :)